# Trying to insert multiple rows ASP Web API with Postman in JSON

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api

I want to insert list of movies into my database with ASP Web Api. My code works when i insert single value from JSON but when i put it in colons it doesn't. I am not sure whether my type of data in MoviesTicketDTO has to be list. Here is my code so far:

**EfCreateMovieCommand.cs**

```cs
public void Execute(MoviesTicketDTO request)
{

    MovieDTO temp = new MovieDTO();
    temp.Name = request.MovieName;

    validator.ValidateAndThrow(temp);

    var movie = new Movies
    {
        Name=request.MovieName
    };

    _context.Movies.Add(movie);
    _context.SaveChanges();
```

**MovieTicketDTO.cs**

```cs
public class MoviesTicketDTO
{
    public string MovieName { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the error message i get in Postman:
[image]

Comment: When you "put it in colons"? Do you mean brackets? Because it seems `MovieName` would need to be a list instead of a string, and brackets would be needed for that

Comment: Change ` public string MovieName` to `public List<string> MovieName`

Comment: I am getting this error when i change it to List<string> http://prntscr.com/u58q3u

Comment: Make sure that `MovieDTO` also is a class with `List<string> Name`

Comment: Does database has to have certain structure because i am still getting error?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, changed the MovieName to `List<string>` or `string[]` in your MoviesTicketDTO class,

Secondly, changed the Execute method to:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public void Execute([FromBody] MoviesTicketDTO request)
    {
       // blabla
    }
```

At last, updated the post model in the postman:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's say we don't want to change the logic you already have for the `Execute` method and `MoviesTicketDTO` class.

But first, we can understand why your Postman throws an error.
The reason is simple it's because your Controller method is expecting a class having a single string property element (`MoviesTicketDTO` has a property `MovieName`, which is `string`), but it's getting a collection of strings from the Postman call.

Now, if we assume that the `Execute` method is working as expected, you can have the following API method:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateMovies(MoviesTicketChangeModel model)
{
  // you are calling the business layer method here
}
```

where `MoviesTicketChangeModel` is:

```cs
public class MoviesTicketChangeModel 
{
    public List<string> MovieNames { get; set; }
}
```

Next instead of changing your existing `MoviesTicketDTO` model, in your business layer code you can create another method accepting `MoviesTicketChangeModel` model, and iterate over the inner collection, calling the `Execute` method the way you were calling before:

```cs
public void UpdateMovieTickets(MoviesTicketChangeModel model) 
{
    foreach(var movieName in model.MovieNames) 
    {
       Execute(new MoviesTicketDTO { name = movieName });
    }
}
```

One thing to remember here is to organize the Exception handling because you need to ask yourself is that ok if one movie may fail to update, but others succeed.

---

The other approach, instead of the above call, can be creating a SQL Stored Procedure and passing the array of strings to it.

If you don't want to deal with SPs but want the bunch of items updated at once via Entity Framework, use the `AddRange` method, but in this case, you will have to change your `Execute` logic a bit.

---

One more thing: in your `Execute` code, I think it will be worth checking if the Movie doesn't exist before adding it to your Movies table.